# Remove \ in a string with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a sample string that looks like the following...

```
 "{:@text=>"\"Question 12\" must be answered when  \"question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9)\" answered"}"
```

I only want to extract the text:

"Question 12 must be answered when question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9) answered"

I tried using this:

```
@object.scan(/@text=>"(.*?)"/).flatten.map{ |msg| msg.gsub(/(\.|\s+)/, '').strip }
```

However that returns just a `\`

What else might I try?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid string. You have the string:

```
 "#{:@text=>"
```

followed by:

```
 \"Question 12\" must be answered when  \"question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9)\" answered"}"
```

Use single quotes:

```
str = '{:@text=>"\"Question 12\" must be answered when  \"question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9)\" answered"}'
```

then

```
puts str.gsub(/\{:@text=>|\"|\\|\}/,'')
  #=> Question 12 must be answered when  question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9) answered
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `/\/|\w+/`

```
[13] pry(main)> str
=> "{:@text=>\"\\\"Question 12\\\" must be answered when  \\\"question 10 / Question 11 (or Question 9)\\\" answered\"}"
[14] pry(main)> str.scan(/\/|\w+/).join(" ")
=> "text Question 12 must be answered when question 10 / Question 11 or Question 9 answered"
```